# Converting human string time between different units of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

Are you aware of a npm module capable of converting human string time to days, hours, seconds or milliseconds preferably using moment.js time units?

It's a little difficult to explain, so here are a few examples:

'1hours' to minutes = 60
'2days' to seconds = 172800
'60seconds' to minutes = 1
'30minutes' to seconds = 1800

Same as above using short hand:
'1h' to minutes = 60
'2d' to seconds = 172800
'60s' to minutes = 1
'30m' to seconds = 1800

These are the string units used by moment.js

```
Key          Shorthand
----------------------
years        y
quarters     Q
months       M
weeks        w
days         d
hours        h
minutes      m
seconds      s
milliseconds ms
```

Or expressed as a function:

```
const convertUnits = (input, format) => {
    // Implementation
};

convertUnits('1hours', 'minutes') // 60
convertUnits('1h', 'm') // 60
```

Or is it possible to do this just using moment? Remember that I don't care about the actual date or time - I merely want the unit conversions mixed in with the human readable units.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using below:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'
import moment from 'moment'
import momentDurationFormat from 'moment-duration-format'

export const convertTime = (time, format = 's') => {

    if(!_.isString(time) || !_.isString(format)){
        return 0;
    }

    const components = time.trim().split(/(\d+)/);
    const digits = parseInt(components[1]);
    const unit = components[2];

    return moment
        .duration(digits, unit)
        .format(format);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [timestring](https://github.com/mike182uk/timestring) library. It parse a human readable time string into a time based value (by default in seconds). As I see, it can all you need:

```
const timestring = require('timestring')
let str = '1d 3h 25m 18s'
let time = timestring(str)
console.log(time) // will log 98718
```

`str` input param can be set without spaces, for example, '1d3h25m18s'